# Spring 3 replacement for isDisabledInThisEnvironment

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm currently converting a test class which extended the Spring class AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests to Spring 3. This abstract class is now deprecated and I should use AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests.

The test class had this method in it:

```
@Override
protected boolean isDisabledInThisEnvironment(String testMethodName)
{
    // Test is only needed for bugfixing and development. Do not check in with this flag on false. 
    return true;
}
```

What is the replacement for this isDisabledInThisEnvironment method?

Comment: This is a feature provided by `ConditionalTestCase`, to get around the fact that JUnit doesn't have the concept of "skip test", like TestNG does. I don't think there *is* a replacement for this, is was likely overlooked during the transition to JUnit4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept is implemented with `@IfProfileValue`. Works with both JUnit and TestNG.

Comment: Note: Spring `@IfProfileValue` only **skips/ignores** the test if the name and value doesn't match and it doesn't **not-run** it. If you want to implement JUnit Categories type of implementation with this you may need to end up extending `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner#runChild` to _not-run_ instead of _ignoring_. This mainly matters if its results are in jenkins.